# Termination Reason: Client.InternalError: Client error on launch

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

please help

How to make sure EC2 is using the custom KMS key; we are using terraform to deploy the EC2 instance, every time the EC2 instance is launched in an auto-scaling group, it crashes with the below error. Seems like the EC2 instance has no access to KMS key

**Error:** *Termination Reason: Client.InternalError: Client error on launch*

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "autoscaling-group" {
  name                 = var.name
  availability_zones   = var.availability_zones
  min_size             = var.min_size
  desired_capacity     = var.desired_capacity
  max_size             = var.max_size
  health_check_type    = "EC2"
  launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.launch_configuration.name
  vpc_zone_identifier  = local.subnet_id
  termination_policies = ["OldestInstance"]
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "launch_configuration" {
  name                        = var.name
  image_id                    = var.ami
  instance_type               = var.instance_type
  iam_instance_profile        = var.iam_instance_profile_name
  security_groups             = [aws_security_group.security_group.id]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "autoscaling-policy" {
  name                      = var.name
  policy_type               = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  estimated_instance_warmup = "90"
  adjustment_type           = "ChangeInCapacity"
  autoscaling_group_name    = aws_autoscaling_group.autoscaling-group.name
}
```

--
Thank you

Comment: The instance role in the profile `iam_instance_profile_name` should have KMS permissions to your key.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thank you All for your support, I was able to resolve; The issue was with the kms key grant for ec2 auto scaling service
we used the below module and the issue got resolved

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/kms_grant

```
resource "aws_kms_grant" "a" {
  name              = "my-grant"
  key_id            = aws_kms_key.a.key_id
  grantee_principal = aws_iam_role.a.arn
  operations        = ["Encrypt", "Decrypt", "GenerateDataKey"]

}
```

Answer (score 6):

[image]This is probably happening because the Auto Scaling Group can't attach the EBS volume to your EC2 instance. Looks like you chose your EBS volume to be encrypted, but the `key policy` in your `customer managed key` in KMS is not having the correct policy for the specific IAM role Autoscaling use, that is `AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling`. You need to add the below policy blocks under the `key policy` for the KMS key used to encrypt the EBS volume:

```
{
            "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::*<AWS Account Number>*:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Allow attachment of persistent resources",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::*<AWS Account Number>*:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:CreateGrant",
                "kms:ListGrants",
                "kms:RevokeGrant"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, we wanted the same in terraform.  got it done by adding the key directly
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/kms_grant

Answer (score 1):

I revolved this error, adding autoscaling role on user in KMS

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the plan with `TF_LOG=DEBUG` to get more details about what is missing. You mostly need a [Service-Linked role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/autoscaling-service-linked-role.html) in order to get pass the permission issue

Comment: Thank you, we could see terraform waiting for the EC2 to become health 

aws_autoscaling_group.autoscaling-group: Still creating... [6m40s elapsed]
aws_autoscaling_group.autoscaling-group: Still creating... [6m50s elapsed]

Answer (score 0):

Command to be executed on Target account:

```
aws kms create-grant --region <Region> --key-id arn:aws:kms:<Region>:111111111111:key/<Key-ID> --grantee-principal arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling --operations "Encrypt" "Decrypt" "ReEncryptFrom" "ReEncryptTo" "GenerateDataKey" "GenerateDataKeyWithoutPlaintext" "DescribeKey" "CreateGrant"
```

- Region: same region where AMI and ASG to be created
- Source account: 111111111111 (AMI from which EBS is encrypted)
- Target account: 999999999999 (ASG to be created from Source account AMI)
- Snapshot KMS Key:  (Go to AMI of Source account and check snapshot)
- IAM Role of Target account:

  ```
  arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/aws-service-role/autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling
  ```

Comment: Besides the key policy, had to run this command too to make the ASG launch works for cross-account CMK-KMS. Ref [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/key-policy-requirements-EBS-encryption.html)